# Determining whether an app is open or closed (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, push-notification

I am using firebase for push notifications, everything works on the push notifications end. I am using the notifications to push a view controller however I need to know whether the application has loaded before I make this call.

I have had a look at how I can determine the app's state however it is not useful to me. I need to determine whether the app has loaded before because if it has loaded and closed (and become inactive) I can push my new view controller no issue. But if the application is killed and loads, I run into issues with some API calls I make. I want to determine the state of the app so that I can appropriately handle a notification to an inactive (but loaded) app or dead (inactive, not open) app.

I have tried 2 methods of doing this:

```
UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];

        if (state == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
            NSLog(@"app is loaded in the background");
            //perform segue immediately to notification screen
        }

        if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
            NSLog(@"app is completely inactive")
            //perform segue to loading screen (where it will then segue to notification screen)
        }
```

Unfortunately it looks like `UIApplicationStateBackground` is to do with background services, which my app doesn't have. In my current case the code for `UIApplicationStateInactive` is always called when I recieve an FCM notification.

The other method I tried was adding a `boolean` to my app's plist and setting it to false whenever the app became inactive. Then checking for the boolean when the app receives the notification and THEN making it active. However this seemed to never work either.

Is there a property I can access that determines whether the app is loaded but inactive, or completely dead and not loaded whatsoever?

Comment: Are you saying that once installed you need to know if this is the first time the app is run or a subsequent time?  Or is it that you want to now if the app is 'open' when it receives the notification?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth I want to know if the app is currently open, not if it is the first time running the app. Imagine the 3 scenarios: 1, the app is open and recieves a notification. 2, the app has been opened and already has a page loaded (you can access it by double tapping home). 3, the app has been fully closed and is launching from fresh. 2 & 3 effect how I enter my app and currently I can't seem to debug this as when you close the app you disconnect the debugger.

Comment: So 1 means running in the foreground, 2 means currently in the background but not terminated and 3 means terminated not running at all?

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Yes. I've currently jimmied up a solution by creating an application state Enum that I save to the app's plist and then executing code based on the stored enum value. However my solution is rather convoluted and I'm sure there has to be an easier way then what I am doing!

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth For 1 & 2,3 there are different methods called by firebase so I have no issues ever with presenting a notification when the app is running in the foreground. The issue is with differentiating between an open but inactive app & a closed app.

Comment: Ok I will add an answer as it's easy to explain the options that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a bit of explanation of the situation faced.  So when a notification is received the app can be in one of three states:

1. Running in the foreground
2. Suspended in the background
3. Terminated

However when the notification is received there are only two methods of receiving it one for state 1 and one for states 2 & 3.

So state 1 can be handled no problem but the issue is how to differentiate between states 2 & 3 in that notification method.

Using a state variable (saved somewhere) for say 'inBackground' and 'terminated' is not going to work because once your app is put in the background you probably won't be told if it is terminated (that's how the app lifecycle works).  So you change your state to 'inBackground' when the app is backgrounded but the user then terminates it and the app is not informed so the state is incorrect.  My companies app does something like this to determine the last state at startup but I am not responsible for that development so I can't say the exact mechanics.

Now in this case you could get around this by removing the just having an 'inBackground' flag which is set when the app is backgrounded and reset when the app is back in the foreground or starts (before any notification is processed).  So when a notification is received you just check this 'inBackground' flag.

However perhaps a better solution is that when a notification is received you put the app in a known state (perhaps return to the initial view controller) and then set the app to the state to respond to the notification.  You do this all invisibly to the user so it just appears to go to the correct place in the app.  This approach has the advantage that it should work for anytime a notification is received.  Of course the exact mechanics of doing this depend on your app.

Right those are my views on it but I need to say I'm by no means an expert on this subject as I haven't played with notifications too much.